# Regex to match all characters except letters and numbers

Tags: php, regex

I want to clean the filenames of all uploaded files. I want to remove all characters except periods, letters and numbers. I'm not good with regex so I thought I would ask here.

Can someone show me how to put this together? I'm using PHP.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by letters. The (until now) proposed solutions only exclude `a-z` and `A-Z` but will all match letters outside these ranges like `é` etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$newfilename=preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9.]/','',$filename);
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. I also forgot to add an underscore. This works but is it optimal? [^a-zA-Z0-9.|_]

Comment: @Timay: If you want to match the underscore, use `[^a-zA-Z0-9._]`, or simpler, `[^.\w]`.

Comment: Wow.. Just those 4 characters will match everything except numbers, letters?

Comment: @Timay: Probably you should read more about regexp (http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Comment: :) Yeah, I agree. I seldom use it but it certainly couldn't hurt. Thank you for your help Kenny.

Comment: Is the backslash an escape character or part of a flag or switch?

Comment: \ in \w is not escape charcter, its shorthand form \w=a-zA-Z0-9_  http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Mark. Kenny, I see that you updated your original answer explaining that what you gave me was a perl expression. I'm sorry I missed that. The regex is exactly the same.

Comment: @S.Mark: He wants to keep the `.` too.

Comment: Exactly. I've settled on using [^.\w] This seems to work well.

Comment: Since no one mentioned it here, `[^\w]` can be shortened down to `\W`. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
s/[^.a-zA-Z\d]//g
```

(This is a Perl expression of how to use the RegExp. In PHP you do:

```
$output = preg_replace('/[^.a-zA-Z\d]/', '', $input);
```

Comment: Thanks Kenny. Will this also match periods?

Comment: @Timay: The `^` means "any characters except". The `.a-zA-Z\d` after that means "period, alphabets and numbers". So it'll match all characters which are not period, alphabets and numbers, then remove them.

Comment: Thank you Kenny. I'm going to plug this in now.

Comment: Kenny, that's not working at all. For example, it does not match (*&^%^

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
$cleanString = preg_replace('#\W#', '', $string);
```

It will remove all but letters and numbers.