# Remove any letter which is not an alphabet or a number?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I use `preg_match` to allow alphabets and numbers in the input,

```
if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $file_rename))
{
$error = true;
echo '<error elementid="file_rename" message="FILE - please use alphabets and numbers only" />';
}
```

What if I want to remove any letter which is not an alphabet or a number?

For instance,

```
test_1
```

to

```
test 1
```

or,

```
test&2
```

to

```
test 2
```

Comment: Instead of "remove", did you mean "replace with a space"? What about multiple occurrences? Are they all replaced with a space each or is it compacted to one single space replacement?

Comment: yes sorry, I mean  "replace with a space" thanks. so `test_&_1` should be replaced as `test   1` then I will replace multiple white space to a single space `preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $string)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex to match all characters except letters and numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167145/regex-to-match-all-characters-except-letters-and-numbers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initially, I'd go with this (unicode safe)

```
$newString = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{N}]/u', ' ', $oldString);
```

If you want to leave existing, multiple spaces alone...

```
$newString = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{N}\s]/u', ' ', $oldString);
```

If you want to compact consecutive non-alpha-numeric characters into a single space, change it to

```
$newString = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{N}]+/u', ' ', $oldString);
// note the + sign
```

Comment: +1 on that ... can't argue with the impossibly exhaustive answer :)

Answer (score 4):

PHP `preg_replace`[<sup>*docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) is what you're looking for:

```
$str = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i', ' ', $str);
```

Note the `i` modifier at the end of the regex -- it makes the search case-insensitive. If you don't mind underscores, you can alternatively just do:

```
$str = preg_replace('/[^\w]/', ' ', $str);
```