# PHP encdoe function for file name

Tags: php, file-upload, encode

I'm learning about the function `urlencode`. Is it possible to use this on a file name? So - when you upload a file to your server and then use that file name later, you would be able to use it in a url?

```
$promotionpicture=$_FILES["promotionpicture"]["name"];
$promotionpicture=rawurlencode($promotionpicture);
```

Then later...

```
$imagesource="http://mysite.com/".$userID."/".$promotionpicture;
```

I'm trying to do this, but every time I navigate to the picture, i get a "Bad request" from my server. Is there a specific php encode function I should use? Or is this wrong all together? Thanks in advance for you help.

Comment: What if not use rawurlencode? It should not make any problems. You really do not need it. Better change the picture name. Generate your own. Think, few users may upload image with same name. That will cause collision in your case.

Comment: Yes, you are just placing the filename on the url and rawurlencode is really not required for that. rawurlencode is used if you want to pass values containing strange characters or symbols.

Comment: Normalize the name of the picture. Better yet, normalize the name of all your uploads

Comment: Might not be the the correct escaping function.  What's the actual target context? Is the URL used for a redirect or in a HTML ´<img>` tag? And the input filename should be sanitized nonetheless, it's client input. Usually a regex, but `basename()` at least.

Comment: So - if i do a check for duplicate filenames later on in my code... how can use something like hash('md5', $_FILES["filename"]["name"]); to make sure the file is easy to handle, but at the same time conserve the extension?

Answer (score 0):

urlencode and similar functions are for making an HTTP friendly URL.  You would want to keep the normal filename and then when printing the img src, use urlencode.

Note that this is not really the preferred way to do it as you can run into duplicate filenames and misc security issues.  It's better to generate a filename for it using a uuid or timestamp or something, that way you can bypass those types of issues.

Answer (score 0):

Pictures are really just raw data, like any other file. It is possible to do something like what you're doing, but not necessarily advisable.

If you want to do something like that, I recommend instead doing something to strip special characters.

```
$newfilename=preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9.]/','',$filename);
```

(from [Regex to match all characters except letters and numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167145/regex-to-match-all-characters-except-letters-and-numbers))

That said, keep in mind what others have said. How will you handle file name collisions? Where will the images be stored and how?

One easy way to do this much more robustly is to store in a database the original file name and the MD5 hash. Save the file by its hash instead of by name, and write a script that retrieves the file by matching the original name to the MD5 using the database. If you store the file type, you can issue correct headers and when the user downloads the file or uses it to embed in a web page, it will retain its original name, or display as expected respectively.

Comment: You actually don't need to explicitly keep the extension. In the database, you'll store the file name which includes the extension. PHP does not require the saved raw data to have the extension, so saving an image as "617a8ad013b50fa7499ffe7e8f6a8be3" is perfectly acceptable.

Passing the header: header('Content-Disposition: filename="'.$fileInfo['fileName'].'"');

Will tell the web browser to name your data on download.